# System.Text.Json serialize array of type to a json object with properties

Tags: json, .net, system.text.json

Using `System.Text.Json`, how can I serialize (and deserialize) an array of **n** elements (classes), to an object of **n** children, where the element name is one of the properties of the object?

For example, by default the following classes

```
public class Project
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public Environment[] Environments {get;set;}
}

public class Environment
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Region {get;set;}
   public Settings Settings {get;set;}
}
public class Settings
{
   public bool OverrideOnFetch {get;set;}
}
```

will be serialized as

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",  
  "environments": [
    {
      "name": "dev",
      "region": "us1",
      "settings": {
        "overrideOnFetch": false
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "prod",
      "region": "us1",
      "settings": {
        "overrideOnFetch": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want to change this behavior and serialize it as

```
 {
   "name": "MyProject",  
   "environments": {
     "dev": {
       "region": "us1",
       "settings": {
         "overrideOnFetch": false
       }
     },
     "prod": {
       "region": "us1",
       "settings": {
         "overrideOnFetch": false
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

without changing the classes (or creating another). As you can see, the `Environment.Name` acts like the property of `environments` in JSON.

I have no idea where to continue from here

```
class ProjectJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Project>
{
   public override Project? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Project value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var namePolicy = options.PropertyNamingPolicy ?? new DefaultJsonNamingPolicy();

        writer.WriteStartObject(); //starts the "project" object
        writer.WriteString(JsonEncodedText.Encode(namePolicy.ConvertName(nameof(value.Name))), value.Name);
        //How to write the "value.Settings" without rewriting everything?

        writer.WriteStartObject(); //starts the "environment" object
        foreach(var env in value.Environments)
        {

        }
        writer.WriteEndObject(); //ends the "environment" object

        writer.WriteEndObject(); //ends the "project" object
    }

    class DefaultJsonNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
    {
        public override string ConvertName(string name)
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can serialize it as `Dictionary<string, Project>` where each of the keys is a name such as `dev`

Comment: hum, that's interesting, but it does not solve everything because the `Environment.Name` property should not be be serialized. I'm now actually trying to make this generic, so that I create a converter for `array of T` and the converter serialize the array as `dictionary<string, t>`, given the _property name_ to be the _key_ and to be removed from the `t` serialization.

Comment: Yes you could make a converter to do this, but the problem is you have no way of specifying constructor parameters for it, so you can't tell it which property to remove and turn into a key. Will it always be `name` on all classes?

Comment: This can be accomplished with JsonConverterAttribute + my custom JsonConverter. In the attribute you specify the property name as string (using nameof)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much simpler solution than manually writing the JSON array, is to serialize and deserialize to/from a `Dictionary` within your converter. Then simply convert to/from a list or array type.

A generic version of this would be:

```cs
public class PropertyToObjectListConverter<T> : JsonConverter<ICollection<T>>
{
    static PropertyInfo _nameProp =
        typeof(T).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyToObjectAttribute)).Any())
        ?? typeof(T).GetProperty("Name");

    static Func<T, string> _getter = _nameProp?.GetMethod?.CreateDelegate<Func<T, string>>() ?? throw new Exception("No getter available");
    static Action<T, string> _setter = _nameProp?.SetMethod?.CreateDelegate<Action<T, string>>() ?? throw new Exception("No setter available");

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) =>
        typeof(ICollection<T>).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);

    public override ICollection<T> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var dict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, T>>(ref reader, options);
        var coll = (ICollection<T>) Activator.CreateInstance(typeToConvert);
        foreach (var kvp in dict)
        {
            var value = kvp.Value;
            _setter(value, kvp.Key);
            coll.Add(value);
        }
        return coll;
    }
    
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ICollection<T> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var dict = value.ToDictionary(_getter);
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, dict, options);
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class JsonPropertyToObjectAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

It looks first for a property with the `JsonPropertyToObject` attribute, otherwise it tries to find a property called `Name`. It must be a `string` type.

Note the use of static getter and setter functions to make the reflection fast, this only works on properties, not fields.

You would use it like this:

```cs
public class Project
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   [JsonConverter(typeof(PropertyToObjectListConverter<Environment>))]
   public Environment[] Environments {get;set;}
}

public class Environment
{
   [JsonIgnore]
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Region {get;set;}
   public Settings Settings {get;set;}
}
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j12bBY)